# DirectShow - how to determine what decompressor to use for preview stream (C#)?

Tags: c#, video, camera, directshow, directshow.net

I am working on existing software that needs an update. Disclaimer: this is my first time working with DirectShow.

Basically, our software allows users to connect several different video devices, including third party devices. Up until this point we have been able to get away with using just an AVIDecompressor. Our new device requires an MJPEGDecompressor. We need to continue supporting both.

I have considered simply detecting the presence of our new device outside of DirectShow and passing an argument that switches between the two decompressors, but I would like third party devices that require the MJPEGDecompressor to also work, so I'd prefer to do some sort of detection in the stream.

I would ideally like to be able to detect which decompressor is required before/during graph initialization. What is the best way to do that and have it work with any device using one of those two decompressors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technology you are asking about in DirectShow is [Intelligent Connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390342): you are not sure which filters you need to connect the parts and DirectShow offers its services to supplies the missing links into the chain using its filter registry.

The referenced page above provides you with details on how exactly Intelligent Connect works, and a shorter answer is this: when you already have an output pin which needs a decompressor and you are not sure which filter is needed and you want to query this before filters are actually added and connected, you can use

> ... Finally, if no suitable filter has been found, the Filter Graph Manager searches the registry, using the `IFilterMapper2::EnumMatchingFilters` method. It tries to match the output pin's preferred media types against media types listed in the registry.

Most likely the Filter Graph Manager would use the same anyway, and it will go over the potential candidates trying one after another until connection is made. when you use this yourselves, you have finer control over the process and you can see the filters before actual connection attempts.

Comment: Is there any way to set it to switch between two particular decompressors (e.g. GraphFields.MJPEGDecompressor and GraphFields.AVIDecompressor) if I have previously added both Filter's using FilterGraph.AddFilter?

I ask because I am concerned that if the user has installed a third party decoder software and EnumMatchingFilters finds those, the performance may suffer compared to the native DirectShow decoder.

Thank you for your answer and any additional information you can provide.

Comment: It's absolutely possible and, more to that, in different ways. If you use one of the Intelligent Connect methods (mentioned at the link I posted) you have decoder supplied for you. However, you can identify JPEG pin, and add decoder yourself using `IGraphBuilder.AddFilter` and `IPin.Connect` methods (you can use even filters that are not available to public). Alternatively, you can use filter graph callback and ban specific filters you don't want from Intelligent Connect.